# Implement generic wrapper when trait function relies on generic marker trait being implemented for Self

Tags: rust, traits

I am currently at a loss for how to reconcile a certain design pattern in Rust. This pattern involves a trait with a generic function that is constrained based on some marker trait. **For the sake of this question assume it is impossible to modify `Foo` or `FooMarker`.** I already know that `do_foo` should have been placed in a separate trait instead of using a marker trait, but I am not the one making that decision.

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn do_foo<T>(&mut self, _: &T) where Self: FooMarker<T>;
    fn do_bar(&mut self);
}

/// Indicates that a specific type is supported for doing Foo.
trait FooMarker<T>: Foo {}
```

This might look reasonable-ish at first, but attempting to work with this pattern in a generic way feels near impossible. For example, take the usually trivial case of a wrapper struct extending the functionality of `Foo`. Initially I thought that this implementation may work as intended, but it runs into a number of issues.

```rust
struct FooWrapper<F> {
    inner_foo: F
}

impl<F: Foo> Foo for FooWrapper<F> {
    fn do_foo<T>(&mut self, x: &T) where Self: FooMarker<T> {
        do_extra_stuff();
        self.inner_foo.do_foo(x)
    }

    fn do_bar(&mut self) {
        self.inner_foo.do_bar();
    }
}

impl<T, F: FooMarker<T>> FooMarker<T> for FooWrapper<F> {}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=168e63928d58f305fbe14068bbeb66a0)
Conceptually we may be able to look at this and know that `FooWrapper<F>: FooMarker<T>` implies `F: FooMarker<T>`, but the compiler does not want to rely on this information. After thinking for a second, this kinda makes sense. Nowhere in `impl Foo for FooWrapper` do we require that `F: FooMarker<T>`.

**How can I write `FooWrapper` *without* rewriting `Foo` or `FooMarker`?**

Comment: [You don't need to make `FooMarker` generic to demonstrate the issue](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa71d24077040ef46e49a67fe560441f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't, unless I'm missing something.

`impl<T, F: FooMarker<T>> FooMarker<T> for FooWrapper<F> {}` tells us that if `F` implements `FooMarker<T>`, then `FooWrapper<F>` also does. But the opposite is not necessarily true, like here:

```rust
struct Bar;
struct Baz;

impl Foo for FooWrapper<Bar> {
    fn do_foo<T>(&mut self, _: &T)
    where
        Self: FooMarker<T>
    {}
}

impl FooMarker<Baz> for FooWrapper<Bar> {}
```

We can't change the `where` clause either, because it is defined in the declaration of `Foo`.

---

The real solution to me would be to make `Foo` itself generic, which I'm understanding you were thinking of:

```rust
trait Foo<T> {
   fn do_foo(&mut self, _: &T);
}
```

Frankly, I've never seen such a "marker" pattern (except maybe in a context where sealed traits are involved, not sure), and I don't see how it helps.

Comment: That is kind of what I was guessing, but it is unfortunate that there is no way to work around it. I was hesitant to label what I was describing as an antipattern, but it seems like that is the case.